# Java - Looking for example comparing nested class with anonymous inner class

Tags: java, class, nested, anonymous

Can someone provide me with a good simple example of a regular nested class and then the same class re-written as an anonymous inner class?

Comment: You can get your IDE to do this.  Create an anonymous inner class and when get your IDE to move the class and refactor it for you.

Comment: stack overflow has lots of answer regarding this i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are examples:

```
 public class Outer {
     public static class NestedStatic implements Runnable {

         public void run(){
             doSomething();

         }
     public static void main(String[] args){
         Thread nestThread=new Thread(new NestedStatic());
         nestThread.start();

         // now anonymous:
         Thread anonThread=new Thread(new Runnable(){
             public void run(){
                 doSomethingElse();
             });
         anonThread.start(); 
     }
}
```